# prevent handling of missing files by other use/get in express

Tags: express

I'd like to keep the contents of the folder `/public` for use of local files by a local app. However, when a file is missing, instead of getting the 404, the user is getting the *index.html* page.

What I would like to do is have user get the 404 when accessing any resource that does not exist for anything under */public/**, but have the react app handle everything else from index.html

this is my setup:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(path.resolve(myPath, 'public')));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(myPath, 'index.html'));
}
```

should the get include a regex to not include `public` matches, or is there a way to handle this with use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've explicitly told express to look into your `public` folder for ANY file that the user requests with this line:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(path.resolve(myPath, 'public')));
```

Express, by default, serves NO files.  It makes nothing public by default.  So, the first thing to do is to remove the line of code that makes that entire directory public.  And, then if you want to serve some specific things from that folder, you need to either make very specific routes to only the files you want to be public or you need to move the "public" files out to a directory where everything can be public and then point `express.static()` at that directory.

Then, you've added another line to respond to any request possible with one file:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(myPath, 'index.html'));
}
```

This is just not really how you should be using express at all.  Here are some steps to think through:

1. Figure out which static files you want Express to serve automatically (without a specific route being made for each file).
2. Then, organize those files so they are in their own sub-directory on your server hard drive.
3. Then, you can point `express.static()` at that directory without any fear of it serving files you don't want to be automatically public.
4. Think about organizing things into a hierarchy (not required, but sometimes simpler to manage) so that `css` files might be one place, client-side `js` another place, etc... such as `/css/css files here` and `/js/js files here` when laying out your hierarchy.  Then, you can control the serving of each type of file separately if wanted and it may make maintenance easier (since separate people often maintain CSS files and JS files).
5. Then, design specific routes you want handled for other types of files.
6. Then, add an error handler route which determines what should be returned to the browser when no other route handler was found.  How to do that is described [here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html).  Also, note that Express has a different default error handler based on whether the NODE_ENV environment variable is set to production or not.
7. Don't use `*` routes that handle everything with the same content, including things you don't want to provide a specific page for.  You don't want search engines to index things that you don't have original content for and you don't want users to bookmark unintended URLs just because you happen to be using `*` in a route handler.

Comment: I think my question wasn't clear, the use is for a local react app. All non-file requests are handled through *index.html*

Comment: @Daniel - I don't think that changes anything.  Your single page app is presumably still making lots of requests from your server (images, CSS files, ajax requests, etc...).  Those are all separate routes on your server whether they are things your client-side Javascript requests or things the browser itself requests.  No difference to your server.  It's job is to just respond to requests no matter how the requests originated.

Comment: @Daniel - And, as my points above indicate, you don't want your server sending content for non-existent routes because that can confuse the heck out of search engines or even get your relevance reduced if you're serving identical content from lots of different routes.

Comment: in my case, the application is not online, so search result are not a concern. When the app is looking for referenced content, the 404 code helps determine if the content (images, css, etc) is missing, because I can use the response code instead of the content

Comment: @Daniel - That doesn't change anything here.  Your server should return a 2xx response when it has content for the URL and a 4xx response when there's no content.  And, the proper way to code the server is not to make it respond with the same content to all possible URLs and then try to exclude some of them.  Just code it to respond to the URLs that it should and let the default handler return a 404 for all other URLs.  You're coding yourself in a box here.

Comment: @Daniel - If you don't care to hear any more about proper design patterns, I can move on to other questions.  I can't really tell if you're not understand my suggestions and therefore I should expend more energy to explain or if you're just telling me you don't want to do it that way for whatever reason so I should just move on.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by adding

```
app.get('/public/*', (req, res) => {
  res.status(404).send(req.path + ' not found');
})
```

Comment: I added a number of things to my answer that offer advice on a better way to structure things.